# Change the color of customized Listview programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I have e ArrayAdapter to make e CustomListView. And here is the full code. I want to set the background color of the XML `R.layout.streampage_custom_row_view`  programmatically from the Java code.

```
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StreamPage_modified.this,
                    R.layout.streampage_custom_row_view, R.id.title, targetArray) {


                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


                    TextView Description = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.description);

                    Log.d("SPOC COUNT", "" + SPOC.size());
                    Log.d("SPOC POSitiON", "" + position);

                    Description.setText(SPOC.get(position).getDescription());

                    return row;
                }

            };
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(StreamPage_modified.this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to `set the background color of ListView's row` than try `row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` // (or any color) inside `getView()`

so your code should be

```
       @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
           row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // or any color 

            TextView Description = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.description);

            Log.d("SPOC COUNT", "" + SPOC.size());
            Log.d("SPOC POSitiON", "" + position);

            Description.setText(SPOC.get(position).getDescription());

            return row;
        }
```